# Combining several csv files and calculating averages of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a folder with several csv files. Each file has several columns but the ones I'm interested in are id, sequence (3 different sequences) and time. See an example of a csv file below. I have over 40 csv files-each file belongs to a different participant.

| id | sequence | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 1 |  |
|  | 2 |  |
|  | 2 |  |
|  | 3 |  |
|  | 1 |  |
|  | 3 |  |
|  | etc |  |

I need to calculate the average times for 3 different sequences for each participant. The code I currently have combines the csv files in one dataframe, selects the columns I'm interested in (id, sequence and time) and calculates the average for each person for 3 conditions, pivots the table to wide format (it's the format I need) and exports this as a csv file. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works. However, for some conditions 'time' is 0. I want to exclude these sequences from the averages. How do I do this? Many thanks in advance.

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('times*.csv'))

df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames))

df_new = df[["id","sequence","time"]]
df_new_ave = df_new.groupby(['id','sequence'] ['time'].mean().reset_index(name='Avg_Score')
df_new_ave_wide = df_new_ave.pivot(index='id', columns='sequence', values='Avg_Score')
df_new_ave_wide.to_csv('final_ave.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

Comment: before the `groupby` line, add `df_new = df_new[df_new['time] != 0]`, is this what you want?

Comment: I think that would work, thank you!